# Kaminari gem doesn't seem to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, installation, rubygems, kaminari

I added "gem 'kaminari'" to my gemfile and ran bundle per the instructions, and it looked like it installed, but I'm getting errors like 'current_page' method not found messages.  The documentation indicates that there should be a kaminari directory created in my app/views directory, but there isn't one.  I'm using rails 3.0.7.  Is there a different/better way of installing this gem?

Thanks

Comment: Is it listed when you run `gem list kaminari`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you have forgotten to run the generator?

```
rails g kaminari:views default
```

That should create your kaminari directory.